# ElasticSearch PostData Serialize insert not working

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

This is my Post Method

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult InsertEmployee([FromForm]Employee model)
    {
      
       
        var Employee = new Employee
        {
            EmpId = 3,
            Name = "asadasasad",
            Country = "pak",
            Gender = false,
            StartDate = DateTime.Now.Date,
            MultiCheck = "3,2,1"
        };

        PostData fromObject = PostData.Serializable(Employee);
        _elasticClient.Index(fromObject, i => i
               .Index("employee"));

        string message = "Failed to create the product. Please try again";
        return Content(message);
    }
```

When this method is used it is increasing the values but not showing on records

http://localhost:9200/employee/_search?typed_keys=true?size=1000

This query return this reponse

[image: This is the Response]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Elastic Search Post Data insert you first need to serialize the object which will dump it into the class then deserialize it and then insert in the elasticsearch using this way

```
                        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NetConnectTransactionDTO>(deserialize);
                        var Response = _elasticClient.Index(data, i => i
                          .Index(NetConnectTransactionIndex));
```